# how to enable HAVE_FWPRINTF in gettext-runtime\intl\printf.c?

Tags: windows, printf, gettext, widechar

I am trying to return locale names on windows system. For this I need to use swprintf() as follow in the code.

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
...


/* Construct the full name of the locale. E.g. "en-US" to
 * "English_United States".
 */
static char *
construct_full_locale_name(wchar_t *locale_name)
{
    char        result[FULL_LOCALE_NAME_LENGTH * 2];
    wchar_t     wc_full_locale_name[FULL_LOCALE_NAME_LENGTH];
    wchar_t     buffer[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
    size_t      len;

    wmemset(wc_full_locale_name, 0, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);

    /*
     * Construct the full name of the locale using GetLocaleInfoEx API by using
     * a few specific flags in the following order.  First, if the locale is
     * valid, we will get the language name in English by using
     * LOCALE_SENGLISHLANGUAGENAME flag. If the locale is invalid we can't get
     * anything so we are returning the locale name as it is. Once the locale
     * is verified, we can proceed to get region using
     * LOCALE_SENGLISHCOUNTRYNAME flag. In the same way, we will get code-page
     * using LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE.
     */
    if (GetLocaleInfoEx(locale_name, LOCALE_SENGLISHLANGUAGENAME,
        (LPWSTR)&buffer, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH))
    {
        int cp;

        len = swprintf(wc_full_locale_name, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH, L"%ls",
                       buffer);
        wmemset(buffer, 0, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
        GetLocaleInfoEx(locale_name, LOCALE_SENGLISHCOUNTRYNAME,
                        (LPWSTR)&buffer,
                        LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
        len += swprintf(wc_full_locale_name + len,
                        LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH - len,
                        L"_%ls", buffer);

        GetLocaleInfoEx(locale_name,
                        LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE | LOCALE_RETURN_NUMBER,
                        (LPWSTR)&cp, sizeof(cp) / sizeof(WCHAR));
        swprintf(wc_full_locale_name + len, FULL_LOCALE_NAME_LENGTH - len,
                 L".%u", cp);
        /*wchar2char() is internally defined function to turn wide-char to char */

        wchar2char(result, wc_full_locale_name, sizeof(wc_full_locale_name),
                   NULL);
    }
        sprintf(result, "%s", locale_messages);

    return result;
}
```

Problem here is, when I build this code on other system I am getting error at runtime **libintl_swprintf** is not found. After some investigation I found that this symbol is related to libintl.h.

```
#undef swprintf
#define swprintf libintl_swprintf
extern LIBINTL_DLL_EXPORTED int swprintf (wchar_t *, size_t, const wchar_t *, ...);
```

This function is defined in gettext-runtime\intl\printf.c

```
...
#if HAVE_FWPRINTF
...
DLL_EXPORTED
  int
  libintl_swprintf (wchar_t *resultbuf, size_t length, const wchar_t *format, ...)
  {
    va_list args;
    int retval;
 
    va_start (args, format);
    retval = libintl_vswprintf (resultbuf, length, format, args);
   va_end (args);
    return retval;
  }
 
 #endif
 
 #endif
```

This function is controlled by **HAVE_FWPRINTF**, I couldn’t find where it is defined in the gettext code, can someone help how to enable this?

Comment: Read the manual for the library you are using. It will explain which customization points it has and how to control building it.

Comment: @IInspectable, I tried but couldn’t find anything from the library manual. But I found that gettext-0.20 does not exports libinl_swprintf() where as it was doing it in previous versions. But they didn’t mention anywhere or maybe I am not looking at right place.